# Can't load a module with custom loader in vue-cli project

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue-cli, webpack-loader

I have a project where Webpack 4.43.0 is set up with vue-cli. I'm trying to use
[image-size-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size-loader) to get image size at build time.

For that, in one of my .vue files I'm trying to load the module using the custom loader I have installed in the project:

```js
const background = require("image-size!../../../../assets/images/candy.jpg");
```

When my project builds, it outputs the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors8:47:03 AM

This dependency was not found:

* image-size!../../../../assets/images/candy.jpg in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/vue/guides/tags/hero/TagGroupInvite.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save image-size!../../../../assets/images/candy.jpg
```

The file is present and js/ts/css files resolve fine. What can be wrong with my setup?

Comment: Could you provide your webpack config?

Comment: @kmgt It is big, created a repository to share it: https://github.com/gvlasov/stackoverflow-question-63720095

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to specify `image-size` as a loader too.

Append this loader to webpack.base.conf.js

```
...
loaders: [
    ...
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'image-size'
    }
    ...
]
...
```

Comment: I specify the loader in `require()`, what's wrong with that? And I don't want every image file to be handled by this loader, only this specific image.